# Declare an unknown number of lists in a type alias

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function that returns a list, which contains a variable number of lists, each of which contains first a variable number of lists, and then a single object as the last member of the list.

Here are a couple output examples:

```
output1 = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        { x: 1, y: 2 }
    ],
    [
        [4, 5, 6],
        { x: 3, y: 4 }
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9],
        { x: 5, y: 6 }
    ]
];

output2 = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        // however many more lists there are
        { x: 1, y: 2 }
    ],
    [
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        ['g', 'h', 'i'],
        // however many more lists there are
        { x: 3, y: 4 }
    ],
    // however many more lists there are
];
```

The contents of the lists can be type `any`, but each object has properties `x` and `y`, each of which have the type `number`.

**How can I create a type alias that accurately and specifically shows this?**

Right now, this is what I have created:

```
type Output = [
    [
        any[], // this is what I need help with
        { x: number, y: number }
    ][]
]
```

Comment: I think the best you can do at the moment is (any[] | { x: number; y: number; })[]. But maybe in the future Rest/Spread properties helps https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103

Comment: Yes that will work until something better comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure isn't well designed, why do you use an array as the top structure and not an object?
Are you stuck with the structure (i.e.: it's a result of a 3rd party lib, or a json result), or can you change it?

If you can change it then I suggest that you do as you'll be able to have more control.

```
type Output = Array<Array<number[] | { x: number, y: number }>>;

let output1: Output = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        { x: 1, y: 2 }
    ],
    [
        [4, 5, 6],
        { x: 3, y: 4 }
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9],
        { x: 5, y: 6 }
    ]
];
```

Comment: Yes, some structure adjustments may be in order, but this will work for now. Just change `number[]` to `any[]` and it solves it. Though as @Magu mentioned, perhaps a better solution will be available soon.

Comment: Why do you need to change `number[]` to `any[]`? You described that it's a number array...  If you use `any`, in most cases, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: For this case, the list contents could be combinations of `string`, `number` or theoretically anything such as `['a', 1, undefined, 4, 'hello']`. I described it as such below my examples.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. If that's the case then I'd use `string | number | boolean` and not `any`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Seems like `any` should be avoided. What if I also wanted to account for something like `['a', 1, [1, 2, 3], { a:1, b:false }, true]` or really 'any' possibility?

Comment: If you really don't care what's in that array then use `any` because that's what it's for..  But in most cases you do care, because you also need to later deal with that data and then to check the type (at runtime) against all of the possible types that you support. So, in your real scenario, what types do you expect to have?